# Can I input one-hot coding vectors not the raw sentences directly into PYTHON module word2vec.Word2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, one-hot-encoding

For example, I've already transformed all the words and numbers into one-hot coding. Then

```py
from gensim.models import word2vec
```

and I want to use

```py
word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=one_hot_vectors)
```

However, it popped up an error:

```py
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('U32')dtype('U32') dtype('U32')
```

I think it is because I cannot directly input one-hot coding to `word2vec.Word2Vec`. I wonder that does python have any other modules to satisfy my needs. I just want to input one-hot coding vectors not the raw sentences directly into word2vec model. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?? Can you explain?? If you are just trying to convert your words to vectors..this is not needed. Are you trying to fine tune it in some way.

Comment: In fact, I don't want to use one-hot coding to represent words. I just want to use my own designed vectors to represent different words. So, I want to feed vectors into gensim not the raw words. Thank you so much.

Comment: from your comments i see that you already have some representations for your words. You want to tamper with(or finetune) those representations. You will have to set the hidden states of your word2vec model to your representations and then train the model just like you would do from scratch. I have tried this and it works. [Refer](https://www.kaggle.com/kfujikawa/word2vec-fine-tuning)

Comment: The author in the link uses glove vectors as his starting point. You can put the representations you already have

Answer (score 0):

No, not with the version of `Word2Vec` in the Python library `gensim`. It expects an iterable sequence of lists-of-words as its `sentences` corpus.

(If you need to use the `gensim` `Word2Vec`, and couldn't feed it the pre-one-hot texts, you could potentially convert your one-hot vectors *back* into word-like tokens. You could convert them into the real original words, if you have the mapping of hot-index-to-original-word, or to plug tokens like `'0'`, `'1'`, etc.)

Comment: In fact, I don't want to use one-hot coding to represent words. I just want to use my own designed vectors to represent different words. For example, I want to use 0 1 0 0 1 to represent apples and 0 1 0 1 0 to represent bananas. The raw vectors themselves have some meanings and I want to use word2vec to generate more meaningful vectors for them. For example, the final representation of word2vec may be 0 1 0 0 0.9 for apples and 0 0.9 0 1 0 for bananas.

Comment: You can certainly modify the word-vectors that the model uses, before training starts. To do this, don't provide a `sentences` at model-instantiation. Instead, instantiate the model without providing the corpus, then call `model.build_vocab(sentences)` to let it discover the vocabulary & perform its normal vector initialization (where all words start as random low-magnitude vectors). Then tamper with the vectors inside the model as you wish. Finally, perform normal training  - which will continue to adjust the vectors.

Comment: `from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec`

`sentences = [['A1','A2'],['B1','A2'],['A1','B2'],['B1','B2'],['B1','A2'],['C1','C2']]`
`model= Word2Vec(min_count=1)`
`model.build_vocab(sentences)`
`model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter) `        Sorry, I still cannot figure out how to tamper with the vectors inside the model after using `model.build_vocab(sentences)`. How can I get the vectors from the model and replace them with my own vectors? Thank you so much.

Comment: @BinchunLu, from your comments i see that you already have some representations for your words. You want to tamper with(or finetune) those representations. You will have to set the hidden states of your word2vec model to your representations and then train the model just like you would do from scratch. I have tried this and it works. [Refer](https://www.kaggle.com/kfujikawa/word2vec-fine-tuning)

Comment: What happen if you try `model.wv['A1'] = your_vector`?